# How to create std::vector subclass with initializer_list support?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, initializer-list

I'm trying to create *MyVector* class that inherits from *std::vector* (to add a few useful methods). Everything works great, but it cannot be initialized with *initializer_list*:

```
    std::vector<int> a = { 4, 2 }; // OK
    MyVector<int> b = { 4, 2 }; // Error
```

Both VS2015 and gcc does not allow compiling it:

```
error: could not convert '{2, 3, 4}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'MyVector<int>'
```

Why so? I tried explicitly adding constructor with *initializer_list* param solves the issue (see code below), but why?? Why isn't it inherited from *std:vector*?

```
template <class T>
class MyVector : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
    // Why is this constructor needed???
    MyVector(const std::initializer_list<T>& il)
        : std::vector<T>(il)
    {
    }
};
```

P.S. I don't want to add this constructor to avoid writing any other constructors...

Comment: *"to add a few useful methods"* -- Are you sure those methods wouldn't be better off as free functions, which take a vector as an argument?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but got puzzled by this problem. In the particular case, I need "getRandomElement()" function and a method seems the appropriate solution here - it's all about the object.

Comment: I don't really understand why you think a method seems more appropriate here. Or what "it's all about the object" means. Sounds like some kind of misguided attempt at strict adherence to OOP, when in fact there's nothing OO about it at all. All you're doing is creating a potentially useful interface function, but arbitrarily restricting its use to this derived class, when it could very easily be applied to any vector, making the interface much more useful. In other words, you're creating difficult-to-reuse code, which could, with minimal effort, be made highly reusable.

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good read for you: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because constructors aren't inherited until you tell them to be.

This is not specific to initializer-lists:

```
struct A
{
   A() = default;
   A(int x) {}
};

struct B : A
{};

int main()
{
   B b{3};   // nope!
}
```

Inherit constructors with the `using` statement, like so:

```
template <class T>
class MyVector : public std::vector<T>
{
   using std::vector<T>::vector;
};
```

By the way, you may wish to consider an `Alloc` template parameter to `MyVector`, instead of forcing the use of vector's default.

Comment: Thanks! Now g++ works, but VS2015 complains:

    error C2886: 'vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>' : symbol cannot be used in a member using-declaration

Comment: Apparently, I was on VS2013 which does not support constructor inheritance, while VS2015 does:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For base-class constructors, C++11 allows a class to specify that base class constructors will be inherited.

so, in your case, you could specify it by using `std::vector<T>::vector;`

```
template <class T>
class MyVector : public std::vector<T>
{
   using std::vector<T>::vector;
};
```